# fancybox2 iframe not working with pagination

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I use fancybox2 to open external links this works fine on the first result page.

moving to the second page causes the iframe to load but its grayed out and a mouse click closes the iframe.

The pagination done by POST, so the page does not refresh, maybe this is the problem?

this is the code for the fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".fancybox-html").fancybox({
    type                : 'iframe',
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var hook = $(this.element).attr('hook');
        this.title = '<li onclick="sendIframeDataToParent(\'' + hook + '\');">Submit</li>'
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by moving the fancybox to window.onload = function()